# too many login attempts bluemix xpages nosql das

Tags: node.js, xpages, ibm-cloud

I'm struggle with building a node.js app using domino access services to get data from a XPages NoSQL database services.

The browser continued sending request and now I got some message telling me I have had too many attempts to login.

I could not find anything in the documentation about it and wonder if I will be able to continue?

As for now, I continue locally, but I do not know what the restrictions are?

Comment: You *might* be blocked by the service provider for a "bruteforce" attempt.

Comment: I think so too and hope for an answer from the provider here since they state they following the bluemix tag on stack overflow. :-)

Comment: Do you have a control panel you can log into?

Comment: Yes, if that is where you are making those calls to

Comment: I have not yet come to the point to deploy the node.js app back to bluemix yet. I run the app locally, but was trying to start to access the No SQL database service. It works towards a local nsf file and my local domino server.

Comment: At the moment I would use the CouchDB istead and not put any time into using the NOSQL service because that is only for experimental and any production release time hasn't been released.

Comment: Yes, I will mark this answer as the answer but it is not any production, I just testing around and playing a little. Do you know any good data migration tools for migrating nsf to CouchDB?

Comment: Have you looked at this video explaining the process -> https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/2015/08/14/combine-xpages-nosql-service-node-js-runtime/

Comment: Use this for CouchDB/Cloudant export: http://notessensei.com/blog/2016/01/the-quick-and-dirty-domino-cloudant-export.html